# How can I check the connection refused in cloud environment?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, virtual-machine

When I use the VM (Ubuntu 16.04) in a cloud, sometimes "Connection refused" is occurred.

I couldn't connect the server more than eight hours.

I asked the reason and check the VM.

But Cloud manager didn't tell me why it occurred and he just reboots it.

Is there any way I can check the reason in my VM?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should have an admin panel or a web panel where you could login and see information about your VM, power on or power off your vm, restart it, configure different settings etc. You should also have an option to start a ssh console for your VM or directly login to a console.

What type of virtualization is used for your VM? OpenVZ? KVM? Other type? Do you have any running firewall on your ubuntu VM?